# Calculate quantity where textbox is a certain value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

**Edit**

So many good answers and all of them work! Thanks a lot guys :) I wish I could mark all of them as solved!

**----**

Good day

Let's say I have these 2 text inputs:

```
<input type="text" id="plt_quantity_sum"/> <!-- this should calculate the "#quantity" where each "#uom_value" is "PLT" -->
<input type="text" id="crt_quantity_sum"/><!-- this should calculate the "#quantity" where each "#uom_value" is "CRT" -->
```

Let's assume the following scenario:

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <th>Item Name</th>
    <th id="uom_value">UOM</th>
    <th id="qty">Quantity</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td id="uom_value">PLT</td>
    <td id="qty">5</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Item 2</td>
    <td class="uom_value">PLT</td>
    <td id="qty">3</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Item 3</td>
    <td id="uom_value">CRT</td>
    <td id="qty">2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Item 4</td>
    <td id="uom_value">CRT</td>
    <td id="qty">3</td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
    </table>
    
    <input type="text" id="plt_quantity_sum" />
    <input type="text" id="crt_quantity_sum" />
```

**What needs to happen:**

When the document loads, or via a button click; the quantity of "#plt_quantity_sum" and "#crt_quantity_sum" should be calculated based on their respective quantities and "UOM" values.

Some Javascript I had in mind which should clarify what exactly needs to happen:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if (document.getElementById("#uom_value").value == "PLT"){ 

document.getElementById("#plt_quantity_sum").value == (sum of #qty); 

}

else if (document.getElementById("#uom_value").value == "CRT"){

document.getElementById("#crt_quantity_sum").value == (sum of #qty); 

}

});
```

Thanks for reading and I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: First, you have 2 input text with the same `id=plt_quantity_sum`

Comment: Yes but I haven't tested it yet, that's just a spelling error. I'll fix it. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: Also what do you want to do withb `document.getElementById(".uom_value")`, it's unvalid? You are targeting  a classname with `getElementById()`??!

Comment: It's just a syntax error. I added some things on my local file and forgot to make the changes.

Comment: I've used ID's for everything now... I just need some help looping through the values and to calculate the quantity, depending on whether or not the "#uom_value" is "PLT" or "CRT".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need declare two variables `crtQtySum` and `pltQtySum` for the two sums and initialize them to `0`, then loop over the tds and check if it's `crt` or `plt` and updtae your variables accordingly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var crtQtySum = 0;
  var pltQtySum = 0;
  $(".uom_value").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() === "CRT") {
      crtQtySum += parseInt($(this).next("td.qty").text());
    } else if ($(this).text() === "PLT") {
      pltQtySum += parseInt($(this).next("td.qty").text());
    }
  });
  $("#plt_quantity_sum").val(pltQtySum);
  $("#crt_quantity_sum").val(crtQtySum);
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var crtQtySum = 0;
  var pltQtySum = 0;
  $(".uom_value").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() === "CRT") {
      crtQtySum += parseInt($(this).next("td.qty").text());
    } else if ($(this).text() === "PLT") {
      pltQtySum += parseInt($(this).next("td.qty").text());
    }
  });
  $("#plt_quantity_sum").val(pltQtySum);
  $("#crt_quantity_sum").val(crtQtySum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Item Name</th>
      <th class="uom_value">UOM</th>
      <th class="qty">Quantity</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Item 1</td>
      <td class="uom_value">PLT</td>
      <td class="qty">5</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Item 2</td>
      <td class="uom_value">PLT</td>
      <td class="qty">3</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Item 3</td>
      <td class="uom_value">CRT</td>
      <td class="qty">2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Item 4</td>
      <td class="uom_value">CRT</td>
      <td class="qty">3</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

PLT:<input type="text" id="plt_quantity_sum" readonly/></br>
CRT:<input type="text" id="crt_quantity_sum" readonly/>
```

**Note:**

I used `readonly` attribute with the inputs, as they're just used to display the sums so they can't be modified, but we could just used a block element for that like `div` or `span`.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for the help mate! Unfortunately I'm rather new to JS; especially using loops and such so this helps me a lot.

Comment: @MailBlade You are welcome, well you just need to focus on using the right selectors for your loops.

Comment: Yeah that's the main thing. I'm not sure how to use and call them. But this has given me a lot of info so thanks again.

Comment: That is superb work. Can't believe you did it so quickly.

Comment: @MailBlade You are welcome, when you get falmiliar with `jQuery` you will find it so easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code. I ve didnt test it.

```
var plt_count = 0;
var crt_count = 0;

$(".uom_value").each(function() {

  if($(this).html === 'PLT'){

    plt_count += parseInt($(this).closest('.qty').html());

  }

  if($(this).html === 'CRT'){

    crt_count += parseInt($(this).closest('.qty').html());

  }

});

$("#plt_quantity_sum").val(plt_count);
$("#crt_quantity_sum").val(crt_count);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll give it a try and let you know :)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from correcting the spelling mistakes that Hamza pointed out, I'd say you should basically iterate through the elements given its class name `document.getElementsByClassName('.someclass')` and then store and sum the value of each one of its siblings with class '.qty'.

Then you take that value and use it to populate the `input` you want.

Hope that helps ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've corrected the spelling mistakes. I forgot to make changes when I copied it from an older local version

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using so many method, this is one of them :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sum_PLT = 0, sum_CRT = 0;
    $('table > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
      tr = $(this)[0];
      cells = tr.cells;
      if(cells[0].textContent != "Item Name"){//To exclude the <th>
         if(cells[1].textContent == "PLT")
           sum_PLT += parseInt(cells[2].textContent);
         else
           sum_CRT += parseInt(cells[2].textContent);
      }
    });
    $("#plt_quantity_sum").val(sum_PLT);
    $("#crt_quantity_sum").val(sum_CRT);
});
```

This is a working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0o1fsqb1/1/).

Comment: Wow thanks for the help man! I really appreciate it! I'm still new to JS. Or I've done some before but never loops and such. I should really get up on my JS knowledge

Comment: I see it doesn't do addition? It takes the quantity of "5" and "3" and makes it "53". Can it be done to calculate the values? So that it's "8"

Comment: @MailBlade I've updated the answer, please check it a gain!
I changed the place of `parseInt()` function!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this code.

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var plt_qty = 0;
        var crt_qty = 0;
        $('.uom_value').each(function(){
            if ($(this).text() === 'PLT' ) {
                plt_qty = plt_qty + parseInt($(this).parent().find('.qty').text());
            }else if ($(this).text() === 'CRT' ) {
                crt_qty = crt_qty + parseInt($(this).parent().find('.qty').text());
            }
        });

        $("#plt_quantity_sum").val(plt_qty);
        $("#crt_quantity_sum").val(crt_qty);
    });
</script>
```

Note : remove class `uom_value` in `<th class="uom_value">UOM</th>`.